# What is the terraform equivalent of "az ad app permission add ..."?

Tags: azure, terraform

I have the following az cli code:

```
az ad app permission add --api '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' --id $app.appId --api-permissions `
    "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6=Scope" `
    "824c81eb-e3f8-4ee6-8f6d-de7f50d565b7=Role"
az ad app permission grant --api 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 --id $app.appId
```

I am looking for the terraform equivalent, but cannot find it. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/r/application.html), you need to within the same command,

```
resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  name                       = "example"
  homepage                   = "https://homepage"
  identifier_uris            = ["https://uri"]
  reply_urls                 = ["https://replyurl"]
  available_to_other_tenants = false
  oauth2_allow_implicit_flow = true
  type                       = "webapp/api"

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

    resource_access {
      id   = "..."
      type = "Role"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = "..."
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = "..."
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

    resource_access {
      id   = "..."
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }

  app_role {
    allowed_member_types = [
      "User",
      "Application",
    ]

    description  = "Admins can manage roles and perform all task actions"
    display_name = "Admin"
    is_enabled   = true
    value        = "Admin"
  }
}
```